# Is transporting people into the countryside and leaving them a legal response for private security?

Tags: united-kingdom, is-x-legal, security

[It is reported](https://www.readingchronicle.co.uk/news/19549203.reading-festival-three-teenagers-dumped-countryside-security/) that three 16-year-olds were found without appropriate authorisation within the camping zone of Reading Festival, UK.  Despite police telling festival organisers no further action would be taken against them they were driven away in the back of a van by Festival security to an unlit and unpaved location three hours’ walk from Reading, along unlit and unpaved roads.  It was at a time that it was pitch black and when the temperature had dropped to nine degrees.

The report states that the security personnel will face disciplinary procedures, but there is no mention of legal sanction.  It seems that this may be illegal, but I do not know what crime it could be (Kidnap, False Imprisonment, Child Abuse)?

Is this legal behaviour?  If not, what charges could be brought against the security personnel?

Comment: Sounds like false imprisonment to me

Comment: @user40812 English case law has established that for false imprisonment you need to be unable to leave in *all directions*. Being abandoned in the middle of nowhere doesn't satisfy the criteria. The van journey is a possibility but only if they were prevented from exiting the vehicle at will.

Comment: Even then false imprisonment may not apply if the purported victim willingly entered into the situation knowing they would be unable to leave. For example, case law has also established that there is no false imprisonment if a car park prevents you from leaving without paying the ticket, because you knew that would happen when you entered.